# Ziggeo: record over existing video?

Tags: video

So I'm testing out Ziggeo's embeddable video recording tech - which looks pretty awesome - but I've hit a stumbling block. For my use case, I need to be able to specify custom keys for a video when it's first recorded - which is easy to do:

```
<ziggeo ziggeo-width=320 ziggeo-height=240 ziggeo-limit=120 
  ziggeo-enforce_duration="true" ziggeo-rerecordings=3
  ziggeo-key="mykey-1-1" />
```

From that tag, you can see that I've also allowed re-recordings, a max duration, and auto-rejection of captured videos that are too long. All good, works like a champ.

Where I'm stuck is that I need to be able to support coming back to this same page in a separate browser visit/session and re-record over the same video, with the same key. And I can't quite figure out how to do that. The closest I've gotten is this version of the ziggeo tag:

```
<ziggeo ziggeo-width=320 ziggeo-height=240 ziggeo-limit=120 
  ziggeo-enforce_duration="true" ziggeo-rerecordings=1
  ziggeo-video="_mykey-1-1"
  ziggeo-modes="rerecorder" ziggeo-perms="forceoverwrite" />
```

(Swapping ziggeo-key for ziggeo-video - with the _ prefix on the key itself, per the docs for embedding a video for playback - is the only way to get the previously recorded video to embed.)

With that code, the original video shows up in the control on page load with a "Re-record?" button (which seems to indicate that the "rerecorder" mode is working as intended), and playback of the existing video works as expected. When I click "Re-record?" the embedded control redraws itself to look like the non-rerecorder control, showing a live camera preview with a "Record" button. When I click the "Record" button, the control redraws again to display a static "Could not create video." message and the browser JS console reports a 404 while trying to postback to a URL like this:

```
http://embed.ziggeo.com/v1/applications/<my_account_token>/videos/_mykey-1-1/streams?<big_token_thingy>
```

...which seems to indicate the re-recorder is looking for the existing video using the "_"-prefixed key.

If I use this slightly different version of the tag, substituting ziggeo-key for ziggeo-video:

```
<ziggeo ziggeo-width=320 ziggeo-height=240 ziggeo-limit=120 
  ziggeo-enforce_duration="true" ziggeo-rerecordings=1
  ziggeo-key="mykey-1-1"
  ziggeo-modes="rerecorder" ziggeo-perms="forceoverwrite" />
```

...then there's no playback available, an error "Could not display cover shot", but the re-recording process works as before - only this time the error is "Forbidden" and the POSTback URL reported in the browser console is:

```
http://embed.ziggeo.com/v1/applications/<my_account_token>/videos?<big_token_thingy>
```

(Presumably the meat-and-potatoes of the record attempt are in the POST params)

Any pointers/tips/advice/thoughts? My hunch is I'm missing something with auth tokens... but I can't quite see how. Love what I've seen of Ziggeo so far, but this use case is sort of a make or break for my ability to move forward with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in true Murphy's Law fashion, right after finishing this post I stumble on the answer:

```
<ziggeo ziggeo-width=320 ziggeo-height=240 ziggeo-limit=120 
  ziggeo-enforce_duration="true" ziggeo-rerecordings=1
  ziggeo-video="_mykey-1-1"
  ziggeo-modes="recorder,rerecorder" />
```

Comment: Follow-up: if a video has been created but not submitted, you'll _still_ need to use the rerecorder version of the tag. We were using webhook "video_ready" callbacks to ultimately determine which version of the tag to use, but that didn't work if the video capture was started but never completed. Tweaking our logic to use "video_created" callbacks got us around that problem.